# App initialisation - IDLE Time enormous

Tags: angularjs, performance

I'm facing some performance issue.
Indeed, the app itself reacts pretty well when it's loaded but my problem is more like when I perform a F5 ( and app reload again), then I see some strange idle time that are killing my app loading time.

When starting my app :

- I do some queries to my webserver : take around 500ms - 700ms
- I present the requested datas
- I have some translation to every text (that generates a lot of watchers)
- I use angular-translate for that. If you have a better solution of internationalisation ;)

When app is started, I have 1200 Watchers. I have tried removed ALL translation and have around 700 watchers but do not see any difference on behaviour.

- I have around 25 Modules loaded, 18 are mandatory for app to run

Well, let's dig to the issue, here is a chrome Timeline representing my problem.
I presented 2 different ones.
[image: IDLE Long_1 - Chrome Timeline]
[image: IDLE Long_2 - Chrome Timeline]

**Any idea why I have those IDLE Times ?**

**Any Idea on how I can investigate more on the root cause of that issue ?**

Edit : Information 09/06/2015

- all my JS code is into appcache, therefore, all my code is loaded at
  app first init, and then into cache.  I have added into appcache all
  vendors / lib / js / fonts / img etc...
- there is during that time 5 or 6 requests that are mainly done into
  the first block. This is a corporation private angularJS app
- from those requests, we granted to the user rights and init the app
- we have tried to remove all HTML generation from the app, and keep only the JS to see if the blocking point was the rendering, no
  effects
- we have tried to remove angular-translate, that generates a lot of watchers for "on the go" translation, no effects

Thank for support,

Comment: What kind of app is it? How many network requests you have? Have you bundled your JavaScript? Used a CDN for your static content? ...

Comment: I edit answer with those info : all my JS code is into appcache, there is during that time 5 or 6 requests that are mainly done into the first block. This is a corporation private angularJS app

Comment: @Dieter Goetelen edit done with more info

Comment: I believe you have probably hit some sort of bug, that being said, no idea where is it located.

Comment: Can you record the whole thing in the Timeline tab and then save it and upload it here? That way people can take a closer look at things.

Comment: As @sirrocco is asking as well: the images you present are not from the _Timeline_ view, but from the _Profiles_. Maybe you can add one from the timeline view as well. Also try to put `console.timestamp('some identifier here');` in your code. This will show up on the timeline as markers. See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#marking-the-timeline for more information.

Comment: @sirrocco & Auke thx. I'll provide those information ASAP. 
Auke,  I have enabled auto timestamp on Chrome Console and I clearly see that I have several seconds where my JS code is "stopped". I ll dig in your link

Comment: @auke, didn't know of the effect of console.timeline. I'll try that !

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one-time binding for parts you only want to show for reading not editing e.g. dynamically generated Tables / Lists ?

Hello {{::name}}!

more [here](https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/speeding-up-angular-js-with-simple-optimizations/135)

Comment: Yes I already did. As mentionned, I have even tried to remove completly the HTML part. to keep only the JS.